# How to run httpd on android?

Tags: android

I would like to run a web server on Android.

Then, how can I run a httpd service on Android?

Thanks.

Comment: About the way you would on any embedded linux, with two major considerations: 1) it will have to run on an unpriveleged port, for example 8080 instead of 80. And 2) you probably can't reach it via the mobile network, it would need to be connected to an externally reachable wifi router which is willing to route to it, or only be used by clients on the local subnet.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to compile httpd for Android. Just install BusyBox (httpd comes with it) and you'll be able to use it. Also install any terminal emulator + root access. Next step:

`$ su`

`# httpd -h /path/to/the/www`

(Type it in the terminal emulator)

The $ sign means you're typing this command as user, # - as root.
Then, next:

`# httpd start`

That's all! If you've placed index.html (index.php) in the right directory, it'll show up right after entering ip_of_the_phone(:80). I haven't discovered yet how to change hostname in the LAN, so you can use IP instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [kWS web server](http://www.appbrain.com/app/kws-android-web-server/org.xeustechnologies.android.kws):

Answer (score 0):

I just ported it but it is untested but it might work. I used a custom built GCC 4.6.1 toolchain to compile it. Had to change the classes and took out some crypto but it should just be a matter of uploading via ssh and running. Of course unmounting your SDcard will crash it.

Maybe someone can work off my code.

http://code.google.com/p/apache-android-httpd